# Problem with setting up constraints for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I wonder how we can fit different screen sizes with lots of textfields e.g. resize the fields/textsizes etc for Swift.

Here is my design at the moment:

https://ibb.co/wQF3rrQ

*Grey = textfields

I've tried with setting constraints and all of that, but it won't work. I can't find myself what's the problem.

Should I set the constraints programmatically rather than in StoryBoard?

Comment: *"I've tried with setting constraints and all of that, but it won't work."* --- show the constraints you've setup and the result that doesn't "work". Are you using stack views? subclassed `UIView`s? Are you setting proportional or absolute constraints? You need to show how far you've gotten, and where **specifically** you are running into problems... Otherwise your question boils down to *"can somebody do this for me?"*

Comment: Problem: I'm setting constraints for iphone8, if I go into smaller screen, e.g. SE, 4s, it won't fit in width neither subView, or textFields etc. Half of the last textField is outside the UI/Screen. I create an image for that to show you, give me 1 min

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZSH4c6r

Comment: OK - so, it looks like you are using fixed-sizes -- fixed widths, fixed spacing, etc. As you can see, that obviously won't work. You need to decide how you want it to look on different screen sizes / ratios, **start** with the smallest size you want to support, and then use proportional / relative constraints to allow the elements to "grow" and/or allow the spacing-between-elements to adjust.

Comment: The thing you talking about "growing" is exactly what I would love to understand how to/accomplish. But I don't find any guide on that, and now I end up crapping it. So yes, fixed width/heights I believe there is! But that were a great advice, to begin with the smallest device and then just let it grow. I'll try that, I think I'm on the way to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you want.

1. Do you see the `Vary For Traits` button in your storyboard, located below your Xcode? There's a use for that. Take a look at `Adaptive Constraints` on Google, and you'll get tons of tutorials. Like this: https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-how-to-add-adaptive-constraints-to-support-a-universal-app-273663475b12
2. Second way is to make use of `multiplier` of your constraint.
3. Third way is the, uhmmm, a usual (or unusual) way of some developers I know. Make reference of each constraints, and toggle their values based on the screensize (or device) of the user.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow, it's very hard. But I'm starting to get it. But I don't understood how I could make textfields resize? The textsize. Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this?